# is Content Security Policy 'unsafe-inline' deprecated?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm developing a Chrome Extension, I tried to add the  'unsafe-inline' CSP as per the [Google Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

However after doing so and attempting to reload my extension at `chrome://extensions/` I'm getting:

`There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
Ignored insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'script-src'.`

For ref the entire CSF as defined in `manifest.json`:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  https://localhost:8000; object-src 'self'"`

So, why am I not able to set 'unsafe-inline'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not deprecated, it's perfectly fine on the web.

However, it's simply not allowed in extensions as a security measure (and frankly, good practices enforcement).

[Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20200414192641/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing) explains what you can and can't do with CSP.

> Up until Chrome 45, there was no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect.
>
> As of Chrome 46, inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See Hash usage for  elements for an example.

Don't use inline scripting - it's not *needed*. The same docs will show how to deal with it.

Comment: Bummer. If only I controlled the contents of the Iframe. Thanks in any case.

Comment: It only applies to your own code. What iframe are you talking about?

Comment: Didn't realize it might matter, but in the extension's background page, I'm loading an Iframe in which I'm loading data from a 3rd party url. It's that url/html that has inline scripts.

Comment: That HTML should have its own CSP isolated from the main CSP. Sounds fishy.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look into it more. Thanks for the references though

Comment: For external pages, you can override CSP by header replacement with `webRequest`; I would use that sparingly though.

Comment: @Xan, Why is it that webpages are allowed to use unsafe-inline yet extensions are not? Shouldn't it be equal for both? Nonsense policy.

Comment: @pacerier Extensions are a highly privileged context, able to do what web code can't. As such, they require stricter security.